# Remove duplicate sitemap.xml from admin 1.9.2.4 ce

Tags: magento-1.9, sitemaps

Sorry if this is covered elsewhere or glaringly simple.
In error, my client has ended up with three entries under `Admin/CatalogGoogle Sitemap`

```
3 /sitemap/sitemap.xml
2 /sitemap.xml
1 /sitemap.xml
```

1 & 2 are as you can see both the same and attempting to write to `sitemap.xml` in the root which has insufficient permissions.
We want to use just the first **(/sitemap/sitemap.xml) file but can't find** **how to delete the other 2** as there's no delete option in `Admin/Catalog/Google Sitemap`.
It's causing `cronjob` issues as the jobs for the 2 in the root are running infinitely.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you Shabbir
Couldn't see it for looking.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the Delete Option when you go to edit mode of sitemap.[image: Sitemap Delete Option]